# Spiky left border in css

Tags: css, border

Suppose I have an element in `display: block` with property `left-margin: solid 3px black`.

How do I make the border three pixels at the top left and one pixel at the bottom left? Here's a diagram of what I mean.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using`border-image`:

```css
b {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-left: solid 3px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000 50%, #fff 63%) 0 0 0 100% / 0 0 0 3px
}
```

```html
<b></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

In below case i have used `:after` to add border effect by adding `skew`

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
}

.parent.left-border {
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.parent:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-2deg);
  transform: skewX(-2deg);
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>

<div class="parent left-border"></div>
```